# Need help figuring out a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

So I have a function fight,which takes two objects in the following manner:

```
fight :: (Combatant a, Combatant b) => (a, b) -> (a, b)
fight (fighter1, fighter2) =
let damageTo1 = ((attack fighter2) - (defense fighter1))
  damageTo2 = ((attack fighter1) - (defense fighter2))
 in (damage fighter1 damageTo1, damage fighter2 damageTo2)
```

The combatant class is as follows:

```
 class Combatant a where
 health  :: a -> Int
 attack  :: a -> Int
 defense :: a -> Int
 level   :: a -> Int
 damage  :: a -> Int -> a
```

I have two object types, Player, and Monster.
The player has to fight monsters around him,so the monsters are actually in a list like [Monster1,Monster2,Monster3,Monster4...etc]
and the player has to fight each single one.. so the function calls would go something like

```
  fight(player,Monster1)
  fight(player,Monster2)....etc..
```

However,I am not exactly sure how to make that happen ..I thought a function like map would be useful here but I'm not sure.. Ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: It's been a while since I used Haskell, but something like `map (\m -> fight(player, m)) monsterList` ought to work. BTW, if you defined your `fight` to simply take two arguments instead of a tuple, (i.e. so it could be called as `fight fighter1 fighter2` ) then the answer would be neater (IMO): `map (fight player) monsterList`

Comment: It's part of a college exercise so we were already given the fight function to take a tuple..thanks for the answer! I shall give it a shot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a fold, a map, or both. Given:

```
class Combatant a where
  health  :: a -> Int
  attack  :: a -> Int
  defense :: a -> Int
  damage  :: a -> Int -> a

data Person = Person { personHP :: Int } deriving Show
data Monster = Monster { monsterHP :: Int } deriving Show

-- We will assume for time that your HP determines your attack.
instance Combatant Person where
  health = personHP
  attack = personHP
  defense _ = 0
  damage (Person hp) dmg = Person (hp - dmg)

instance Combatant Monster where
  health = monsterHP
  attack = monsterHP
  defense _ = 0
  damage (Monster hp) dmg = Monster (hp - dmg)

fight :: (Combatant a, Combatant b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
fight fighter1 fighter2 =
  let damageTo1 = attack fighter2 - defense fighter1
      damageTo2 = attack fighter1 - defense fighter2
  in (damage fighter1 damageTo1, damage fighter2 damageTo2)
```

To do this, it's best to split up `fight` so that it only returns the first combatant. As `fight` is symmetrical, we can figure out what happens to the second combatant by reversing the order of our arguments. That looks like this

```
fight :: (Combatant a, Combatant b) => a -> b -> a
fight fighter1 fighter2 =
  damage fighter1 (attack fighter2 - defense fighter1)
```

and this

```
λ> fight (Person 10) (Monster 5)
Person {personHP = 5}
λ> (flip fight) (Person 10) (Monster 5)
Monster {monsterHP = -5}
λ> fight (Monster 5) (Person 10)
Monster {monsterHP = -5}
```

Given a list of monsters and a single person:

```
λ> let person = Person 15
λ> let monsters = map Monster [1..4]
λ> monsters
[Monster {monsterHP = 1},Monster {monsterHP = 2},Monster {monsterHP = 3},Monster {monsterHP = 4}]
```

We're probably interested in asking two questions:

- What happens to the player after her encounter with all the monsters?
- What happens to each monster after her encounter with the player?

The second question is dispatched with a map, as @Aky mentioned.

```
λ> map (`fight` person) monsters
[Monster {monsterHP = -14},Monster {monsterHP = -13},Monster {monsterHP = -12},Monster {monsterHP = -11}]
```

Ouch. Whereas the answer to the first question might look like this:

```
λ> fight (fight (fight person (monsters !! 0)) (monsters !! 1)) (monsters !! 2) -- ... ugh, how tiresome ...
```

But this is what functional programmers call a *fold left*, which in Haskell goes by the `foldl'` function (ignore the baroque apostrophe).

```
λ> foldl' _ person monsters    
<interactive>:137:8:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: Person -> Monster -> Person
λ> foldl' fight person monsters
Person {personHP = 5}
```